# Custom formatting with a formula

Tags: google-sheets

Suppose I have 3 cells, like so:

```
13:00 | Westminster Abbey | 14:00
```

The middle cell I want to apply a custom format to so that it reformats to "1 hour at Westminster Abbey" or something like that.

The first hurdle is to get the formatting to work *at all* with anything that isn't a number.

The second hurdle is that even if it *were* a number, it doesn't look like I can include even so little as the contents of another cell in the format. If I put `0"!"` like the format, it'll happily put a `!` after any number I enter. If I put something like `0"=A1"` it will show `=A1` *literally* in the cell. Same if I enter something like `"=CONCATENATE("0",E8)"` it will literally show the formula, and not evaluate it.

To re-emphasize: I want this in the **custom format**, not in a regular formula! All the above is possible with a formula, but I want to put just the text in the cell that I care about. I prefer not to have a bunch of formulas in place of clean text.

So, the question remains:

How can I automatically have the contents of a cell formatted, where the format includes the contents of another cell by means of a formula?

Or just:

How can I achieve what I illustrated at the start?

Answer (score 1):

the issue here is that you can't. custom cell formatting is not build to handle such stuff. best you can have is to hard format it like:

[image: 0]

Comment: I was afraid of that. Isn't there another feature that does what I want? One that I might not be aware of?

Comment: nope, there isn't. these kinds of stuff are always dealt with regular in cell formulas